# Printing forms from CIC permanent resident portal

Tags: resident-permit, canada, paperwork, forms

Has anybody who applied for permanent residence on the Canadian immigration portal figured out how to print out already filled online immigration forms for purpose of validation and keeping personal records?

I talk about web-based forms, like imm0008 and imm5669 supported by [CIC PR portal](https://prson-srpel.apps.cic.gc.ca), rather than their pdf versions.

Forms are large,span to several screens wisards style and for some categories of applicants include all travel/job/study history, so typos are inevitable.

According to the portal each screen of the form should be printed right after being filled. When I try with Google Chrome or even Firefox I get only sidebar printed rather then my data.

Note. I already figured out a few workaround, and tried to elaborate on them at technical discussion boards, but was directed here. The previous technical discussion is at
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/173007/revisions

Update. After paying the processing fee and submitting a form one can download the submitted forms (now printable). But I guess, you cannot withdraw, correct errors and resubmit without paying again or violating the user agreements.

Answer (score 1):

Since I get no comment or answer I report my current finding.

Apparently to print a form pages/screens one should first reduce width of browser window (e.g. Firefox) until the sidebar disappear. Otherwise the printing would not be particularly successful.

Regretfully each page/screen of a form should be printed individually, so owners of slower printers may prefer to first dump each page into a pdf file, and then print all in a batch job.

PS. Perhaps the traversal of form screens/pages can be automated with some Greasemonkey, Selenium, web-scrapper or other web automation software or browser plugin, yet it might be be case/form-specific, and I am not sure what is CIC stance toward web tools.

PPS. Advanced users can intercept form GET Requests  JSON data payload e.g. using Network panel of Developer Tools of the browser , but you need perform serious massaging (a number of transformation) to get a human friendly document from raw data.